# How can I send multiple answer poll using Telethon (user can select more then one options)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

I did my best but I'm unable to find a resource and my current code sends an anonymous poll but I want to send '**Multiple Answer poll**' so one user can choose more than one option.

also, how do the bot will know which option is pressed?

```
await bot.send_message(event.chat.id, file=InputMediaPoll(
                poll=Poll(id=event.chat.id, question="This is a test poll",answers=[PollAnswer('Option 1', b'1'), PollAnswer('Option 2', b'2')])))
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/poll.html) you should use poll constructor with `multiple_choice` set to `True`:

```py
from telethon import types


await bot.send_message(
    event.chat_id,
    file=types.InputMediaPoll(
        poll=types.Poll(
            id=1,
            question="This is a test poll",
            answers=[types.PollAnswer('Option 1', b'1'), types.PollAnswer('Option 2', b'2')],
            multiple_choice=True
        ),
    )
)
```

To know your voters just get this poll message in any way and check the results.